# Java GUI Crash happens over VNC!

Tags: java, user-interface, swing, awt

I have a Java GUI based Application. When I run it on Windows it works fine. But when I am in vnc session to a Linux Box **without X11 graphics** enabled. Out of 20 runs of the software on an average 1 run fails to bring up the GUI in two different ways,

- The GUI ***shrinks to a small square***.
- The GUI ***doesn't appear*** at all.

Comment: What does "without X11 graphics" mean?

Comment: it means that the vnc session is running on Bare Graphics mode. You generally find it in .vnc/xstartup file of your home directory.

Answer (score 1):

> ...without X11 graphics enabled.

Assuming you are [*Using Headless Mode*](http://java.sun.com/developer/technicalArticles/J2SE/Desktop/headless/), be sure that you construct your GUI on the [event dispatch thread](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/initial.html); otherwise, the result is indeterminate.